# How to append a breadcrumb to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, breadcrumbs

I have a function which has breadcrumbs

```
_constructBreadCrumb : function(){
    $.ui.breadcrumb = $('<ul class="testBreadCrumb"><li><a class ="TestCodeView" href="#testCodeView">CodeTest</a></li></ul>');
},
```

Then I have another function which appends the breadcrumbs and some other functionalities

```
_constructApp : function(container) {                           
    var widget = this;                           
    $('<ul/>').appendTo(container)
    .append($._constructBreadCrumb)
    .append('<li><a class="layoutViewButton" href="#layoutView"><i>Layout</i></a</li>')
    .append('<li><a class="codeViewButton" href="#codeView"><i>Code</i></a></li>')
    .append('<li><a class="liveViewButton" href="#liveView"><i>Preview</i></a></li>');
    //more code to load the rest of the features
```

I am not able to load the breadcrumb when I add append. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.
PS: I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to debug your scripts. This way you can see if you have an error and inspect the html changes live.

Comment: I use firebug, there are no errors. It's just that it's not getting added.

Comment: Please place a link to this plugin

Comment: @machineaddict Sorry, did not understand. :(

Comment: What's the plugin name and where did you downloaded it? I cannot help if I don't test the plugin.

Comment: Heyyy, it's not a plugin actually the project that I am working is a variation of the Rapid interface Builder developed by Intel (Open Source Project). The entire code is in jQuery and HTML is all created dynamically.There are basically 3 views Layout, Code and Preview. I can go into the details are give you a link to their original source as well. The breadcrumb and stuff fits into it. Would you like me to give you the link?